# R write multiple hyperlinks into one excel cell

Tags: r, excel, hyperlink

I'm using R, and would like to write several hyperlinks into one excel cell. In this cell, labels of these hyperlinks will be comma separated. I know a R function xlsx::addHyperlink to write hyperlinks in xlsx, however, I don't find a way to write multiple hyperlinks into one cell.

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The default nature of Excel is one hyperlink per cell and it is non-negotiable.  That said, there is a workaround but it requires a manual update.

Over the hyperlink labels you would need to insert a shape (e.g. box) and set the fill and border options to none and then add the hyperlink to the shape.  I've left the border color on the images to show what I mean.

[image]